# Extract Python variable using Bash command

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell

I have to execute Python script named `run_sql.py` having a variable called `res` which is equal to 4.ie `res=4`.

How to extract the value of `res` using Bash command?
Below code is what I tried/automated

```
bash_command='python3 /services/python_sql.py -dev /sql_path/audit.sql;echo $res'.format(i),
```

In other word I have to extract value 4 from `bash_command` as I am using it in airflow

Any suggestion or help will be of Great use

Comment: Does the python script _output_ the variable's value? It's unclear where that variable is declared.

Comment: yeah..It is displaying the output value

Comment: **res** is a shell variable, right? 
Are you trying to run that shell command (_bash_command_) and then from the output, get the value of **res** that is displayed by the echo?

Comment: @JorgeGx,res is a variable[present in run_sql.py] .I need to extract that value using bash command

Comment: Then `res=$(python3 script.py)` will capture the value into a shell variable "res".

Comment: @glennjackman,Thanks,What you are telling is echo `res=$(python3 /services/python_sql.py)`,will capture value of res variable that is already present in `python_sql.py` file???? OR is there any way I can do Like  echo$1,$2 ect

Comment: That will capture the value that the python script **outputs**. It can't reach into the python interpreter to extract a variable's value. The python script has to cooperate by printing the value (which you say it does)

Comment: @glennjackman,Thanks,will chk and inform you.and how about other sql file...